# "Time's up" or "time up" for games

Tags: grammaticality, colloquialisms

I have seen games using both forms *time's up* and *time up* to say that the time is up. Which is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They both mean *the time is up*, that is, the time allotted for this activity has expired. *Time's up* is a contracted form, and *time up* is an ellipted form. Which you use depends on context.

Comment: I have never heard *time up* in my life, only *time’s up*.

Comment: @tchrist: But the OP has, or at least seen it.

Comment: @tchrist Check my comment above, the Bejeweled game uses it on speed mode.

Comment: @J.R., It is the same usage, you you play till the end of the 1 minute match, the Time Up comes on the screen, indicating that time has expired.

Answer (score 3):

I think "time's up" is correct. It's a contraction for "time is up" (obviously). "Time up" seems to have no verb. It's just a noun and a preposition. Perhaps games that use "time up" are made in non-English-speaking countries. Foreign games often have slight missteps in colloquialisms.

Comment: "Time out" is common enough in the United States, where sports need breaks for advertising

Comment: The bejeweled uses Time up, when playing speed mode.

Here is a Link:
http://bejeweled.popcap.com/html5/0.9.12.9490/html5/Bejeweled.html

Comment: @Henry: except that "Time out" is an entirely different construction. There's no implied 'is':'Time is out' would not make sense/would mean something completely different.